# No Reverse Match when applying django_restframework_api_key in django admin page

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying out the [django_restframework_api_key](https://florimondmanca.github.io/djangorestframework-api-key/guide/#api-key-models) library. I am trying out the example in the API Key models in the user guide with a little bit of tweaking.

**Issue**: When trying to save the api key in the Django Admin Page, I get a No Reverse Match Error. Here's the page where I hit save and then get an error: [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/606HE.png)

**Error**: Here's the error, I get:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/clients/clientapikey/add/
raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'clients_clientapikey_change' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin\\/clients\\/clientapikey\\/(?P<object_id>.+)\\/change\\/$']
```

**Project name**: api_key_project

**App Name**: clients

**Django Version**: 3.0.1

**Python Version**: 3.6.9

The clients/model.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from rest_framework_api_key.models import AbstractAPIKey
# Create your models here.

class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ClientAPIKey(AbstractAPIKey):
    client = models.ForeignKey(
        Client,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="api_keys",
    )
```

The clients/admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Client, ClientAPIKey

admin.site.register(Client)
admin.site.register(ClientAPIKey)
```

Installed app section of api_key_project:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'clients',
    'rest_framework',
  'rest_framework_api_key',
]
```

The original AbstractAPIKey model of the library can be found [here](https://github.com/florimondmanca/djangorestframework-api-key/blob/master/rest_framework_api_key/models.py)

Any ideas where I am going wrong? Should I add something to my app urls.py ?

Comment: looks like this library does not support django 3. I am not sure if this issue is occurring because of django version, try to downgrade your django version to v2.2 then check.

Comment: @NalinDobhal It didn't help. It shows the same error with 2.2. I doing something fundamentally wrong, it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`djangorestframework-api-key` maintainer here.

To add a custom API key model to the admin, you need to register a subclass of `APIKeyModelAdmin`, not the API key model itself:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework_api_key.admin import APIKeyModelAdmin
from .models import ClientAPIKey

@admin.register(ClientAPIKey)
class ClientAPIKeyModelAdmin(APIKeyModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Full instructions are documented in the [Admin panel docs](https://florimondmanca.github.io/djangorestframework-api-key/guide/#admin-panel) under `https://florimondmanca.github.io/`